# Dynamically selected variables in plotly do not render correctly when saved in list but work

Tags: r, dynamic, plotly, r-plotly

please see the toy example below that reproduces the error.

The print statement inside the loop works as expected and 3 different charts are produced.

However when "lst" is run after the loop, I expected the same 3 different charts to be rendered but I just get 3 copies of the same (third) chart.

("get()" works when using the the dynamically selected plot directly but putting it in the list, messes it up.)

```
library(plotly)

lst <- list()
cnt <- 1
for(bar in c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")){
  lst[[cnt]] <- plot_ly(data = iris,
                        x = ~Sepal.Length,
                        y = ~get(bar),
                        type = "scatter",
                        mode = "markers")
  print(lst[[cnt]] %>% layout(title = paste(bar, "printed in loop")))
  cnt <- cnt + 1
}
lst
```

Changing "~get(bar)" to the below solves it. I would be grateful for an explanation.

```
y = as.formula(paste0("~", bar))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to render the plotly objects before passing it to your list using `plotly_build()`:

```
library(plotly)

lst <- list()
for(bar in c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")){
  lst[[bar]] <- plot_ly(data = iris,
                        x = ~Sepal.Length,
                        y = ~get(bar),
                        type = "scatter",
                        mode = "markers") %>% plotly_build()
  print(lst[[bar]] %>% layout(title = paste(bar, "printed in loop")))
}

lst$Sepal.Width
lst$Petal.Length
lst$Petal.Width
```